# How to remove index.php and redirect to https by single redirection in Codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

In `Codeigniter` framework i use `htaccess` rewrite for redirect all url's to https

Then i removed `index.php` from url by htaccess.

This cause two 301 redirection.
[image]

**I want to do this with a single redirection . single redirection to redirect all url's to https and remove index.php in same time.
How can i do this ?**

Comment: posy your htaccess code with question, also see base_url().

Comment: @DevsiOdedra I think my code is not needed here . it's htaccess problem not related codeigniter configuration